# Javascript code showing before rendering

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have a PHP website and I am using a jquery AJAX event to access my database. The problem is when the results are returned I can briefly see the raw javascript code and then it is eventually rendered. Can anyone help by explaining to me why this happens and also how I can fix such a situation.

****************   **Edit**  ***************************

Below is a snippet of where i am adding my javascript code. I do this just before the closing body tag.

```
    </div>  
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script><!--JQuery UI-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/c3/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/manageMarks.js"></script>
</body>
```

A snippet of my external file is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#careerSearch').on('click', '.hsSubject', function(){
    var sbjCode = $(this).attr('data-subName');
    var user = $(this).attr('data-user');
    var path = $(this).attr('data-path');
    event.stopPropagation();

    if(sbjCode=='L.O' || sbjCode=='English FAL' || sbjCode=='Afrikaans FAL'){

    } else{
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'includes/highSchoolFiles/careerSearchFiles/suggestionsHandler.php',
            data:{sbjCode: sbjCode, user:user, path:path},
            success: function(data){
                $('.subSearchBody').html(data);
            }
        }).error(function(){
            alert('An Error Has Occured');
        });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Please provide code.

Comment: Is the JS in the head of the document?

Comment: @Seano666 no its just before the footer

Comment: If you are using jQuery, jQuery's $(document).ready() (within either script tags within the head or in an external file referenced in the head) is preferable to putting your JavaScript code right before the footer.

Comment: one of the reason, may be `<script></script>` tag not closed properly, may b you missing `>` or `/`, provide code snippet.

Comment: Please check the edits i put up.

Comment: What's being returned by the suggestionHandler.php?

Comment: Its returning html formatted code.

Comment: Can you provide returned code. It seems that HTML is malformed somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jquery library link in head section.

Comment: my jquery library is not in the head, its just before the closing body tag.

Comment: usually when you use CDN links in the end of document its load when all the documents is loaded and more over its download from online. that's why your code shows as jquery is not there but it comes back when jquery is loaded. to avoid this u either can use library in head section or put your code in between<script> <!--    code     //--> </script> like this.